# Why the image dimensions of bachground image of tkinter get currepted after launching this function?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have created a small search engine with the help of tkinter but when I try to search the background image's dimensions get currepted and it gets small.

```
# Imports
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk 


# Window and Configure
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("2020x1280")
root.title("F.R.I.D.A.Y")
root.state("zoomed")
root.configure(highlightthickness=0,highlightbackground="black")
root.overrideredirect(1) #Remove border
root.overrideredirect(True) 

# BackGround Image
from PIL import Image
Image1=Image.open("1.png")


# Background Image
image1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image1)
window=tk.Label(root,image=image1,borderwidth=0)
window.pack()


def Maximize():
    root.overrideredirect(True) 
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.overrideredirect(False)
    root.state(newstate='zoomed')
    root.overrideredirect(3) #Remove border
    root.update()
    return
 
def search_on_google(query):

    root.update_idletasks()
    root.overrideredirect(False)
    root.state(newstate='iconic')
    root.update()
    import pywhatkit as kit
    kit.search(query)


Maximize_Button = tk.Button(root,text="M",font=("",11,"bold"),borderwidth=0,pady=3,cursor="hand2",padx=7,command=Maximize)
Maximize_Button.place(x=1430,y=0)

exit_Button = tk.Button(root,text="❌",bg="red",font=("",11,"bold"),borderwidth=0,pady=3,padx=7,cursor="hand2",command=exit)
exit_Button.place(x=1490,y=0)

Run_Button = tk.Button(root,text="R",bg="grey",fg="Red",font=("",16,"bold"),borderwidth=0,padx=6,cursor="hand2",command=lambda:search_on_google("python"))
Run_Button.place(x=0,y=80)

root.mainloop()
```

[After searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNc1I.png)

And also why after minimizing the window by shortcuts like (Windo + MM) the whole window disappears without having a icon to reopen it through taskbar.

Comment: Typo error missing single or double quotes on filename `Image1=Image.open('1.png')`